# SSAS : An unexpected error occurred (file 'mdmapha.cpp', line 625, function 'MDMapHandle::Init')

Tags: ssas, cube, ssas-2008

What is this error in SSAS cube processing? Has someone faced this error before and how was it resolved?

Comment: Open a support case. If you can reproduce it consistently that's a straightforward case. That should never happen.

Comment: Hey Greg, thanks for the reply. My cube refresh is continuously failing. And when you say "That should never happen" does that mean my SSAS installation is corrupted or what?

Comment: Just means you hit a bug likely. Upgrade to the latest service pack (and preferably the latest cumulative update), confirm it still is not working the open a support case.

Comment: It was giving this error in ProcessAdd. What I did was a ProcessFull and it seems it's disappeared. Not sure what was the root cause but seems like it's working now.

Comment: How long does ProcessFull take? If it doesn't take too long for your needs then don't bother with ProcessAdd

Comment: This instance it took same time as ProcessAdd but in general it takes a lot more than processAdd.